# Lit app inside React app not deploying in Netlify

Tags: javascript, package.json, netlify, lit, netlify-cli

I have a lit app inside a react app. When I try to deploy in Netlify the app I get this error:

```
build.command from netlify.toml                               
    8:07:44 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
    8:07:44 PM: ​
    8:07:44 PM: $ npm run build
    8:07:44 PM: > react-football-predictor@0.1.0 build
    8:07:44 PM: > react-scripts build cd src/lit-project-football && npm install
    8:07:46 PM: Creating an optimized production build...
    8:07:51 PM: Failed to compile.
    8:07:51 PM: 
    8:07:51 PM: Module not found: Error: Can"t resolve "lit/directives/style-map.js" in "/opt/build/repo/src/lit-project-football/src"
```

I import like this, works locally fine:

```
import { styleMap } from "lit/directives/style-map.js";
```

You can see I try `cd to the src/lit-project-football && npm install` on the npm run build of the root package.json

This should install lit that is the nested package.json

Any ideas?

Comment: The output says `react-scripts build cd src/lit-project-football && npm install` which to me makes it seem like it's running `react-scripts build` where the following strings might be treated as arguments, rather than actually cd-ing and npm installing. You may want to do the cd and npm install in a separate step before the react-scripts build or restructure the projects into a monorepo so all dependencies are installed in one step.